# Inserting String Array through CSV format in ClickHouse db

Tags: clickhouse

I have a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
    v1 Int32, 
    a1 Array(Int32), 
    s2 Array(String)
) ENGINE = Memory
```

but can't figure out how to insert String array:

```
insert into t1 format CSV 1,"[1,2]","[a1,a2]"
```

fails with the following error:

```
Exception on client:
Code: 26. DB::Exception: Cannot parse quoted string: expected opening     quote: 
Could not print diagnostic info because two last rows aren't in    buffer (rare case)
: (at row 1)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry, re-read documentation and found that Strings in arrays should be wrapped by single quote.

```
 insert into t1 format CSV 1,"[1,2]","['a1','a2']"
```

Answer (score 3):

In case it helps anyone arriving here, there's a few non-standard CSV requirements for importing array columns, included object mapped columns too.

##### Arrays: []

- Empty or Single entry are unquoted: [] or [75]
- Multiple entry are quote wrapped: "[6,73,74]"

##### Objects: {}

- Integer keys are always unquoted
- String keys are always sinhgle quoted
- Populated object {} are quote wrapped: "{95:26}" or "{'a':26}"

| desc | arrField | arrdesc | objField | objDesc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| empty | [] | no quotes | {} | no quotes |
| single int key | [10] | no quotes | "{10:20}" | wrap in " |
| single str key | ['ten'] | single quote | "{'ten':20}" | ' (key) and wrap in " |
| single str key val |  |  | "{'ten':'twenty'}" | ' (key and val) and wrap in " |
| multi arr/ob | "[6,73,74]" | wrap in " | "{6:6,73:8,74:4}" | wrap in " |

Example CSV raw - note the lack of double quotes.

```
one,two,three
[75],"{95:26}","{'a':66}"
[75],"{75:2}",{}
"[6,73,74]","{6:6,73:8,74:4}","{'a':8,'b':9,'c':6}"
"[340,272,205]","{340:2,272:2,205:2,206:2,208:2,141:2,142:4}","{'a':7}"
[204],"{204:2}",{}
"[142,141,73]","{142:2,141:4,73:4}","{'a':2,'b':4}"
[74],"{74:20}","{'a':36}"
"[5,74,73]","{5:2,74:10,73:8}","{'a':17}"
```